# Read a text file from to specific line

Tags: php

How do I read from a specified line to a specified line?

```
### users

user name : albert
user name : asqkut
user name : ahddrt
user name : khert

### info

line 1 
line 2
line 3
....



### banned

192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

i want to know how to read from ### info and stop at ### banned to get the date in between

thanks for your help

Comment: looks like  a real good reason to start using a db

Comment: i will explain more i have db with 3 tables users and info and banned what im trying here is to read from let say ### info and export the date between i know how to export that to my db but im stuck at how to read from a specific ### ...

Comment: you say text file i refer to a relational database such as MySQL

Comment: `while(fgets($fh)!='### info'){/*do nothing*/} while($line=fgets($fh)!='### banned'){/*do something*/}` +1 to Dagon though. If you're pulling this from an actual database you've picked a crappy export format.

Comment: yes all what i want to know is how to read from ### info and stop at ### banned to get the data between

Comment: @Fred-ii- noooo one of my worst answers, so inefficient

Comment: @Dagon t'was just a link I found over under "Related" lol didn't know it was yours. I'll delete. Edit: deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your text file doesn't have many `\n\n` like this :

```
### users
user name : albert
user name : asqkut
user name : ahddrt
user name : khert
### info
line 1 
line 2
line 3
....
### banned
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

you can get your data in an array like this

```
$lines = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$start = strpos($lines, "### info");
$end = strpos($lines, "### banned");
$result = explode("\r\n",substr($lines, $start+10,$end-$start-11));
var_dump($result);
```

The result you'll get is

```
 array (size=4)
  0 => string 'line 1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'line 2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'line 3' (length=6)
  3 => string '....
' (length=5)
```

Comment: you're welcome, It would be nice if you set it as correct answer and you made a positive vote :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the SplFileObj, which allows you to seek right to the line, assuming you know the line you want, otherwise you can iterate over them easily.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php